# Ioncube Says Installed, but App (social engine) Says Its Not

Tags: php, mysql, socialengine, ioncube

I tried to install the trial version of social engine.
https://waitress.megaservices.co.nz/

Its say's i need to install ioncube. But when ioncube says its already installed.
https://waitress.megaservices.co.nz/ioncube/loader-wizard.php

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I tried google, but couldn't find any solution.
Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dude, Ioncube is the software to encrypt the trail code of socialengine. You can't move forward without installing it to the main installation. But after all the installation has been done you'll get encrypted code. So don't waste your time in socialengine. It's the worst kind of template I've ever seen and worked with. Everything requires money(although I'm not an ATM) here. Go for basic Zend or Drupal... you'll get freedom.